# Unique value counter from columns with different number of rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to get a count of how many times a unique name (separated into weekly columns) has shown up in past weeks. I've tried countif and a number of other equations but I've run into issues because the length of the weekly lists changes from week to week. From what I've read on microsofts walkthrough all rows of data have to be of the same length for countif to work.

I have the weekly data arranged into columns of names. Looking to have a counter in column A look at column B's names and count how many times those have shown up in all previous Columns probably C:M. Each column has about 200 names.

I've tried and failed with the below equation that I came up with after `=countifs` wouldn't give me anything but the number of columns that I asked it to look at. This equation also has just returned the number of columns I ask it to look at.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,B2),1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(D:D,B2),1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(E:E,B2),1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(F:F,B2),1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(G:G,B2),1,0)
```

---

I was able to figure it out. Previous formula wasn't working because I had my calculation options set to manual instead of automatic this was the reason why my original formula wasn't working.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your current table data plus what you want to achieve. Use the `code` formatting to adjust the output.

Comment: Adding to sina here, this is too complex a task to solve with only the text description. Add some pictures to explain the issue and we might be able to help.

Comment: Your formula is only counting max 1 per column, unless you deliberately want to do that then it would be easier to use pnuts suggestion in the comment below, i.e. use a single range in a single COUNTIF function

Comment: Yes I only want it to count once per column. I know it sounds screwy but it just has to do with the type of data and what we are using it for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right couldn't you just use

```
=countif("A:ZZ","Name")
```